# Function which gives in output name of vector

Tags: r

I'm searching this for a while and I can't find the answer. Is there some function which gives name of the vector ? It's very important to me to have such. Like in the example following.

```
 long_name<-c(1,2,3)
    vec_name<-function(vec){} 
    vec_name(long_name) 
    long_name
```

Comment: Have you tried `names(long_name)`?

Comment: Yes, it gives NULL in output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `substitute`?

```
vec_name <- function(vec) {
  substitute(vec)
}
```

which gives

```
> vec_name(long_name)
long_name
```

Comment: This is simpler, +1,  though why not just use `quote`, without needing to wrap in a function?

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks, yours is great too, +1. It seems `quote` gives `vec` rather than `long_name`

Comment: I mean as in isn't `vec_name(long_name)` the same as `quote(long_name)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, they are the same

Answer (score 3):

You could use `match.call`:

```r
long_name <- c(1, 2, 3)

vec_name <- function(vec) as.character(as.list(match.call())[[2]])

vec_name(long_name) 
#> [1] "long_name"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Kinda interesting, It's really working regardless to vector you put in. How would you do that without function ? It's non intuitive because I don't see that you used vec directly in a function

Comment: @John how do you mean "without function"? If you wanted you could do `as.character(quote(long_name))`